# How can I add padding to a View?

Tags: android

I am trying to make a `View` as a divider on my application to separate two elements (two Buttons, two TextViews or whatever) and I would like to have a padding on the left and on the right of that `View` (to move the background some space on the left and on the right).

It allows you to set a padding but the `View` still continues occupying the full width screen. Here is the code I have:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
```

How can I set a space on the left and on the right of that `View` so the divider will be smaller than screen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using marginLeft and marginRight instead of padding

Comment: @ShashankUdupa From [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html): Even though a view can define a padding, it does not provide any support for margins.

Comment: I have used margins multiple times to create dividers. The width should be match_parent I think to extend your view to full screen. Then given margins left and right of desired size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it. As on [`Android documentation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) it says: *Even though a view can define a padding, it does not provide any support for margins*, I am not able to use `marginLeft` or `marginRight` properties.

If you try to set directly `android:marginLeft="10dp"` you will get the following error:

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'marginLeft' in package 'android'

Nevertheless, you can use `android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"` and `android:layout_marginRight="10dp"` to get the desired result.

The final `View` xml will be like this:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

use margins instead of padding

```
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
```

Comment: From [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html): Even though a view can define a padding, it does not provide any support for margins.

Comment: @Erro404 "Even though a view can define a padding, it does not provide any support for margins" Document is referring for content of View not View. A view can use tag both padding and margin because it is inside view group, but if you define any view inside view you cannot use margin to the inner view.

Comment: yes view directly supports padding, but not margin. margin is based on the view's parent layout. so make the view's width to match parent and set left right margins like "Shashank Udupa" said. The parent layout will resize your view according to the margin you set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not allow to use `marginLeft` or `marginRight` properties. Look at my answer to see the error that it throws, finally I got it :)

Answer (score 1):

Padding takes care of the inner space. Therefore you would use padding to increase the space between the outline of the view and the elements inside it, whether they are buttons, textviews etc.

Margin takes care of the outer space. You would use this to increase the space between the outline of the view and the element which contains it. Hence what you need. To implement this in a view use the following:

```
private void setMargins (View view, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    if (view.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        p.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
        view.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much for answer! I knew the differences about padding/margin (never is bad moment to remember it) but as I was not allowed to set a margin I tried setting a padding. Finally I got the `android:layout_marginLeft` property to do it :)